# How to parse a value from an XML tag in C language?

Tags: c, xml, parsing

I'm getting this string as an input "`<operator value=1/>`".
How in C can I parse out this string to get the "1" back?

Comment: That's not a well-formed XML, btw. attribute values should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: might not be xml. Is the string supposed to be a snippet of Xml ? or is it some legacy, like sgml ?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that that's exactly the type of string you'll always get, you can just use `sscanf()`:

```
int value;
if(sscanf(theString, "<operator value=%d/>", &value) == 1)
    ;  // parsing succeeded, use value
else
    ;  // parsing failed
```

If you're going to be receiving more complex input, I recommend using an XML parsing library such as [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) or [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) (requires C++).

Comment: But I need to extract the "1". This value may differ from time to time. So the String will look the same but the value can change. Can I still use sscanf to just retrieve whatever is between = and / ?

Comment: If I could I'd give you 1 point extra for checking the return value of sscanf()

Comment: @goe: Yes, if the value you're looking for is an integer, this will accept any integer in place of "1".  If you're looking for a string in general, you'll have to something more complex.

Comment: so I can't do: sscanf(theString, "<operator value=%s/>", &string)

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming your parsing the string without using any library and the string may not be legal. I once encountered this problem when parsing sgml.

there are a few ways to do this. You could use strstok to split the string to find the value 1, then convert it using atoi.

I would recommend you use a regex library to extract the string. It would handle more boundary cases.